# How to use deployApp method in shiny

Tags: git, shiny

when I use deploy App failed withe below error message:

```
rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "D:/project/elder-po")
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 86423...
Error in findLocalRepoForPkg(pkg, repos, fatal = fatal) : 
  No package 'rCharts' found in local repositories specified
```

Can any one help me out how to fix this messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully deployed my app using rCharts installing instructions in below website

http://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/

Thank you